# How to add column with numeric range of ID's after grouping data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-manipulation

In the data I have fields "ItemName" and "ID". I need to group rows by "ItemName" and somehow make a "human readable" range of sequential numbers in "ID". I was attempting to do it using Power Query with no luck. What tools or HowTo's do I need to know to get something like in the example image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little work, but this works as long as your data in columns A and B are correctly sorted. Columns C through E have conditional formats to simply eyeball the results to better determine the rules needed for column F.

**Cell C2 formula:** (determine if a new Item Name appears when compared to the prior row):

```
=IF(B2=B1,1,0)
```

**Cell D2 formula:** (determine if the ID is in sequential order when compared to the prior row):

```
=IFERROR(IF(A1+1=A2,1,0),0)
```

**Cell E2 formula:** (OBSOLETE Column, determine if the ID is in sequential order with the following row. Only added this column because I didn't know if it was needed while building this):

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2+1=A3,1,0),0)
```

**Cell F2 formula**: (deterimine if we're starting a new sequence, which is triggered when C is 0 or D is 0):

```
=IF(OR(C2=0,D2=0),1,0)
```

Next, column G is going to build a group based on Name and Sequential rules previously laid out. In G2, I simply entered a hardcoded value of 101. The cells below it will be using formulas.

**Cell G3 formula:**

```
=F3+G2
```

Drag down all your formulas. Next, copy column G and paste as special values into column I, and then remove duplicates.

**Cell J2 Formula:** (to get the name associated with the sequence group):

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(I2,G:G))
```

**Cell K2 formula:** (to get the minimum ID associated with the sequence group):

```
=MINIFS(A:A,B:B,J2,G:G,I2)
```

**Cell L2 formula:** (to get the maximium ID associated with the sequence group):

```
=MAXIFS(A:A,B:B,J2,G:G,I2)
```

**Cell M2 formula:** (to build your sequence range):

```
=IF(K2=L2,K2,CONCAT(K2, " - ", L2))
```

**Cell N2 formula:** (bring over the name):

```
=J2
```

Drag down your formulas. Your final output is found in columns M and N.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*To solve the issue you need a helper data column:*

**::Caveat::**

- *Create group on name was the crucial issue, since ID has to be divided into 2 groups for same name i.e. `Name1`, so that the best way I applied was the HELPER DATA column.*
- *Expecting that someone will share a better & more efficient method.*

---

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell C65:

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(A65),"",(IF(AND(LEN(A65)=4,A65<1300),"NMG1",IF(AND(LEN(A65)=4,A65>=1300),"NMG2","NMG3"))))
  ```
- An array (CSE) formula in cell E65:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($C$65:$C$75, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$64:E64, $C$65:$C$75), 0)),"")}
  ```
- An array (CSE) formula in cell D65:

  ```
  {=IF(E65<>"",MIN(IF($C$65:$C$75=E65,$A$65:$A$75))&" - "&MAX(($C$65:$C$75=$E65)*$A$65:$A$75),"")}
  ```

---

**N.B.**

- Finish array (CSE) formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.